# display images stored as byte array in html control

Tags: vb.net

I am storing a note created with images in my SQL DB.

The html is stored as string like so
eg:

```
<pre lang="c#">
    &lt;div class=&quot;WordSection1&quot;&gt;
        Image 1&lt;br&gt;
        &lt;img width=&quot;237&quot; height=&quot;97&quot; id=&quot;Picture_x0020_2&quot; src=&quot;cid:image001.png&quot;&gt;&lt;br&gt;
    </div>
</pre>
```

And the content of `image0001.png` is stored as a byte array.

how do I display the note with the image displayed
right now it displays a 'X' where the image should be

Please assist

Answer (score 0):

Got the solution

```
Dim array() As Byte = File.ReadAllBytes("C:\image.PNG")
 Dim base64string As String = System.Convert.ToBase64String(array, 0, array.Length)
 Dim str As String = "<div class=WordSection1>Image 1<br><img width=237 height=97 id=Picture_x0020_2 src=data:image/png;base64," + base64string + "></div>"
WebBrowser1.DocumentText = str
```